# Sharing cookies between 2 ProxyFactory (RESTEasy)

Tags: resteasy

I am currently training and I'm working on Android application that uses RESTEasy API and I encounter some problem with ProxyFactory.create method (..., ...).

Let me explain it:

I have two REST services.

**AuthenticateService :**

```
    @Path("/authent/tokens")
    public interface AuthenticateService {

    // This method add a data "token" in cookie    
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public PostCustomerOutput createToken(PostCustomerInput postCustomerInput) throws ConnectException;

    @Path("/{id}")
    @DELETE
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Void deleteToken(@PathParam("id") String token);
}
```

**EnrollmentService :**

```
 @Path("/enrollment/otp")
    public interface UserEnrollmentService {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public PostGenerateOTPOutput postGenerateOTP(PostGenerateOTPInput postGenerateOTPInput);

    @POST
    @Path("/check")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public OutputImpl postCheckOTP(PostCheckOTPInput postCheckOTPInput);
}
```

On these two services, I have a interceptor that handles recovered data in Cookies.

**GrantAccessInterceptor :**

```
public class GrantAccessInterceptor extends AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor {
    public GrantAccessInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.USER_STREAM);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);

    if (null != request) {
        // Read http header to get cookie/
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            if (cookies != null) {
                for (Cookie cook : cookies) {
                    if (cook.getName().equals("token")) {
                        log.info("Token find in cookies");
                        // TODO : do what I want with the cookie
                    }
                }
            } else {
                log.info("Cookies are empty !");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Now I wrote the following test :

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testCreateToken() {

    RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    // Recover AuthenticateService 
    AuthenticateService authenticateService = ProxyFactory.create(AuthenticateService.class, urlLocal, executor);
    // Recover UserEnrollmentService 
    UserEnrollmentService userEnrollmentService = ProxyFactory.create(UserEnrollmentService.class, urlLocal, executor);

    PostCustomerInput in = new PostCustomerInput();
    // put data in PostCustomerInput
    PostCustomerOutput out = authenticateService.createToken(in);
    // authenticateService.deleteToken(out.getCustomerToken());
    PostGenerateOTPInput postGenerateOTPInput = new PostGenerateOTPInput();
    userEnrollmentService.postGenerateOTP(postGenerateOTPInput);
}
```

When I call the method `authenticateService.createToken`, my `GrantAccessInterceptor` shows me the right message "Cookies are empty!" This is normal because the cookie is added to the createToken method.
Now, if I call `deleteToken` method on the same service *(AuthenticateService)* I get the message "Token find in cookies" which is OK.

Until then all is well.

Now, if after calling the method createToken of `AuthenticateService` I call a method of my UserEnrollmentService,  GrantAccessInterceptor finds nothing in cookies ... -> "Cookies are empty!"

I think that the problem comes from `ProxyFactory` which does not share cookies between differents services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `ProxyFactory`'s job to handle cookies, that's up to the `ClientExecutor`.

By passing the same `ClientExecutor` to `ProxyFactory`, you should be able to share cookies:

```
ApacheHttpClient4Executor executor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor();
ProxyFactory.create(ServiceIntf1.class, "http://my-service-url", executor);
ProxyFactory.create(ServiceIntf1.class, "http://my-service-url", executor);
```